# Spring application doesn't start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

when i try to start the Spring application it say:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.0)

2021-06-08 17:14:47.142  INFO 2168 --- [           main] c.g.c.ChefinapocketApplication           : Starting ChefinapocketApplication using Java 1.8.0_281 on my-macbook.local with PID 2168 (/Users/smoushiegoushie/jami31/Springworkspace/Chef in  a pocket 2/chefinapocket/target/classes started by smoushiegoushie in /Users/smoushiegoushie/jami31/Springworkspace/Chef in  a pocket 2/chefinapocket)
2021-06-08 17:14:47.150  INFO 2168 --- [           main] c.g.c.ChefinapocketApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-06-08 17:14:48.328 ERROR 2168 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.generation.chefinapocket.ChefinapocketApplication.main(ChefinapocketApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.generation.chefinapocket.Context] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/generation/utility/dao/Database has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2021-06-08 17:14:48.415  WARN 2168 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.generation.chefinapocket.Context] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:890) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:878) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:865) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:806) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) [spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.generation.chefinapocket.ChefinapocketApplication.main(ChefinapocketApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/generation/utility/dao/Database has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

The problem seems to have something to do with my context class(`@Configuration`), if it is empty it works but if i put some `@Bean`s inside it doesn't work any more. I use a utility jar and it say that it was compiled with java compiler 59 , and that i have 52 but i should have the same compiler and in others projects it doesn't give me the same problems.

Comment: Generally if you include snippets of your code (enough to reproduce the problem) you will get more helpful answers from SO

Answer (score 0):

The class file for `com.generation.utility.dao.Database` contains Java 15 level byte code (class file version 59) and you are running your application using Java 8 which only supports class file versions up to and including 52.

You either need to recompile your utility jar to contain Java 8-compatible class files or you need to run your application using Java 15.

Comment: yeah that was the problem ty, im new to programming and to stackOverflow ill try to do a better job next time i have an issue.